# simpleXML: parsing XML to output only an elements attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm attempting to parse an XML file using simpleXML, but I keep running into issues (mind you I'm a PHP noob.)

This is the structure of the XML file.. (Naming convention used for readability.)

```
<World>
  <Continent Name="North America" Status="" >
   <Country Name="United States of America" Status="">
     <City Name="New York" Status="" />
     <City Name="Chicago" Status="" />
   </Country>
  </Continent>
</World>
```

All of the data is set as attributes (not my decision.) I need to be able to output the name attribute of each of these, as well as a second attribute that tells the status. The "Continents" will be unique, but each "Continent" is allowed to have multiple "Countries" and "Cities."

This is the PHP that I currently have...

```
<?php
        $xml_file = '/path';
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

        foreach($xml->Continent as $continent) {
            echo "<div class='continent'>".$continent['Name']."<span class='status'>".$continent['Status']."</span></div>";
            echo "<div class='country'>".$continent->Country['Name']."<span class='status'>".$continent->Country['Status']."</span></div>";
            echo "<div class='city'>".$continent->Country->City['Name']."<span class='status'>".$continent->Country->City['Status']."</span></div>";
         }

?>
```

How can I avoid having to repeat myself and going level by level using ->? I thought I could use xpath, but I had a tough time getting started. Also, how can I make sure all of the cities show up and not just the first one?

Comment: you need three nested `foreach`'s: (1) `foreach Continent`, (2) `foreach Country`, and (3) `foreach City`. this way you're covering other contents in your xml doc

Comment: I thought about that, and perhaps I was completely botching it, but when I nested the foreach's, it would return all of the correct Continent names, but then each Continent returned the Countries of the first Continent. (i.e. North America: U.S., Canada | South America: U.S., Canada | Africa: U.S., Canada) and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably not "cycling" the countries and cities:

```
<?php
    $xml_file = '/path';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

    foreach($xml->Continent as $continent) {
        echo "<div class='continent'>".$continent['Name']."<span class='status'>".$continent['Status']."</span>";
        foreach($continent->Country as $country) {
            echo "<div class='country'>".$country['Name']."<span class='status'>".$country['Status']."</span>";
            foreach($country->City as $city) {
                echo "<div class='city'>".$city['Name']."<span class='status'>".$city['Status']."</span></div>";
            }
            echo "</div>"; // close Country div
        }
        echo "</div>"; // close Continent div
    }
?>
```

Comment: you beat me too it, I was going to type it out a little differently and probably would have been wrong and more lengthy, i was thinking from the xPath point of view I think rather than from PHP Point of View. PHP is not my Native Language..lol

Comment: Just saw a little flaw in the cycle's logic :)

Comment: gotta love PHP's "verbosity"... B)

Comment: brilliant, thank you! I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking.

Comment: once I saw what you wrote it clicked!